# Wordpress Website- Server error and backup issue

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

For last two days, i have analyzed that my website ( https://www.hptourism.org/ ) took too long to respond and server issue is evident, so i am going to change my hosting server. But first i need to take backup of my whole website so i have added new plugin ( all in one migration ) but when i am trying to create backup then after 64% it shown an error "out of disk space. unable to write content to file. file". I have seen lot's of videos and forums to fix this but still i am unable to fix this error. Please tell how can i fix this issue. My website is wordpress cms.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

there's another way to backup your content, Zip all the wp files then download it then extract it to the new hosting. note you will also need to import the database.